# I want to apply a difference boolean using a collection and not an object

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

So basically I am pretty new to blender and so far I have finished only 3 projects using some tutorials. Currently I am trying to build a cabinet for pc. I created a cube and also created a collection of objects to be differentiated from the mesh so that I can have holes on the back side of the cabinet(For the air ventilation).

The problem is that I want to differentiate the entire collection. I tried doing it with the Bool Tool but when I click on differentiate it also applies my solidify modifier. The brush boolean thing seems to work but then I have to apply it for every modifier of the brush. Is there any way around this.Also I cant add the solidify modifier after the boolean because it is messing up the mesh
Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: @Gorgious Oh really? Thats great then..Will have to update..Thank you very much..Also upload your response as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: @JachymMichal Thank you for the response but there is actually no specific screenshot related to the problem.. Also as Gorgious said I will try updating to the latest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with [Version 2.91](https://www.blender.org/download/) you can use a collection as input in a [Boolean modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html).

Warning : The *Exact* solver can be quite slow when used with multiple meshes. I suggest setting it to *Fast* first.

[image]

Comment: and how do I use that in Python?

Comment: operand_type="COLLECTION"