# Boolean modifier with collections

Tags: modifiers, collections

I'm trying to apply a boolean difference to a collection but it doesn't seem to be taking affect.  I'm using Blender 2.93.4

[image: img1]

I hide the cutter hoping to see holes going through the three objects but no holes?  I've also tried it using the **exact solver**

[image: img2]

Attached Blend File

[image]

Comment: well I think you did it wrong way... cutters are supposed to be in the collection and object you want to cut is out of collection (it works if I try it that way)

Comment: @MikoCG strange that's not how they teach it see link below....but if it works for you.  https://youtu.be/Nb65av9ffgY

Comment: You can't add modifier to collections, what you are seeing in the properties interface is the active object (which is hidden)'s modifiers

Comment: see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212544/86891

Comment: @Gorgious ok, but the holes still aren't showing up if I hide the cutter cylinder object (which is just an object)

Comment: In your case what you should do is remove the collection boolean, and add individual boolean modifiers to each of your 3 objects inside Collection_objects, and set the mode to Object and select your cutter_object

Comment: Ok so basically the old way...I just thought if you have objects in a collection you could apply a boolean to it and it would make one hole straight through all the objects in the collection with out having to creating 3 separate booleans.

Comment: Yeah it's not currently possible to do that. It does work the other way around, if you want to cut 1 object with many objects. You can however use Geometry Nodes to achieve it but for now it loses all geometry data like UVs so it's not really practical See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/228276/86891 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231013/how-do-i-deform-an-entire-collection-lattice/231024#231024 for instance

Comment: @RickT They are not teaching differently... in the video you've linked he is putting the cutters into the collection, and the object that should be cut has the Boolean modifier. Exactly what MikoCG told you.